# Split archives into 2 columns

Tags: php, css, archive

I am trying to make my archives display posts into 2 columns. Any suggestions? Below is the code I have so far and the css classes. I can't find the correct way to modify the css classes in order to display this right. The problem is that I get broken columns with unequal row heights and come up with 1 post on first row, 2 on the second, 1 on the third and so on.

CSS

```
 .half {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 24px;
}

.ng-row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.ng-row:after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content:'';
}
```

CODE

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            
            <?php if($i == 0) {
              echo '<div class="ng-row">';} ?>
                <div class="half">
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                </div>
             <?php $i++; if($i == 2) {$i = 0;
             echo '</div>';}?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php if($i > 0) {echo '</div>';}?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'pagination' ); ?>

    <?php else: ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can we see what you have already tried? Compiled HTML code as well as the relevant CSS?

Comment: Hi I modified the code to show you what I've done so far and added some css.

Comment: We'll need more of your code, *compiled*, to understand your issue. This is basically the code you've given and as you can see, nothing looks wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/3zx674w1/

Comment: Can I post the link in which the problem appears?

Comment: As per Stack Overflow guidelines, it is preferred to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You can set up such an example on JSFiddle.net for example.

Comment: I don't have any more code. That's it. The problem is that the items are not displaying the one next to another as in two columns. There is one column on the left with 5 posts one under the other and at the 5th post of that colum n, the right column starts on the right having nothing to the left

Comment: You are posting PHP code, not the HTML code your PHP outputs. That is what we need to grasp your problem. Although if I understand your issue correctly, you want to show articles alternatively on the left then the right, correct? If so you don't need to add extra HTML to do so, only CSS with possibly a flexbox approach.

Comment: Turned out that the code was wrong. I managed to find the correct one, after several tries. I am updating my answer with the correct last one now.